# Modify Existing Google Calendar Events

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Below is the script I created to modify existing calendar events. My goal is to change the description to have it change from a Register button to Registration Closed. The script works in that it will add guests, however it will not update the description to the new description when the max number of registrants has been exceeded. I did not include the part of the script that details the calProperties.

```
function modifyEvents() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Events");
    var sheetR = ss.getSheetByName("Registration");
    var headerRows = 1;
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i in data; ++i) {
        if (i << headerRows) {
            var row = data[i];
            var room = row[5];
            var description = row[6];
            var agegroup = row[7];
            var registration = row[8];
            var max = row[10];
            var calname = row[14];
            var eventId = row[15];
            var registrants = row[17];
            var calendarName = sheet.getRange(headerRows + i, 15).getValue();
            var calendarId = calProperties.getProperty(calendarName);
            var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
            var id = sheet.getRange(headerRows + i, 16).getValue();
            var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
            var email = sheetR.getRange(headerRows + i, 8).getValue();
            row[10] = sheet.getRange(headerRows + i, 11).getValue();
            row[17] = sheet.getRange(headerRows + i, 18).getValue();
                if (registration === 'Y' && registrants >> max) {//7.1 line 25
                    var description1 = (description + '\n' + '\n' + room + '\n' + '\nEvent Type: ' + calname + '\n' + '\nAge Group: ' + agegroup)
                    var descriptionHTML = '\n <div id="registration_button" ><a style="text-align:right;color:white!important;text-decoration:bold;background-color:rgb(209,72,54);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgb(221,75,57),rgb(209,72,54));color:#ffffff;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);border-radius:2px;display:inline-block;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;height:27px;line-height:27px;padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;white-space:nowrap;text-decoration:none;color:white" target="_blank">Registration Closed</a>';
                    var descriptionRegistration = (description1 + '\n' + '\n' + descriptionHTML);
                    event.setDescription(descriptionRegistration);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know what this is doing?  registrants >> max - did you mean >= ?

Comment: you intentionally are doing bitwise operators?  because it doesn't read like that is what you meant

Comment: I guess I assumed it meant only greater than? I didn't want it to be equal to, because the room can hold the max number and if it's equal to then the number allowed to register will be 1 less.

Comment: I tried it with >= instead and it worked!

Comment: @ScottSelby does "if (i << headerRows) {" not work in a less than only as well?

Comment: I created an answer for you to accept if that fixed your problem ,  you can use > without the equals sign if you don't want the same number to pass , you just want greater than or less than

Answer (score 0):

replace `(i << headerRows)`

with  `(i < headerRows)`

and replace `registration === 'Y' && registrants >> max`

with `registration === 'Y' && registrants > max`

there is a difference between `>` and `>=` which are greater than , greater than or equal to and :

`>>`  `<<`  which are bitwise operands left and right which you clearly did not want

`<<`  [left shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift) Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeroes from the right.

`>>` [Sign-propagating right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift) Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off.

What you want are `>` Greater Than "The greater than operator returns true if the left operand is greater than the right operand."

or

`<` Less Than "The less than operator returns true if the left operand is less than the right operand."

Comment: I changed them to < and the script says Finished almost immediately and nothing happens.

Comment: previosuly I had it as if (i < headerRows) continue;, but I ran it through JSLint and it was unacceptable for that format. So i removed the continue;, and added the { along with anoth < and it worked "the same." I assumed < was the same as <<, it does not do what it's suppose to with only one <. I'm guessing since << isn't the same, then I should go back to the "continue;" format?

Comment: edited , you definetly want greater than and less than ,  if those aren't working then you need to check the actual values of the variables and see what they really are